# How to Remove Duplicate Statement

Tags: sql-server

How to delete duplicate data row in SQL Server where there are not any unique value differences? I remain only one statement from my sales table (`dbo.Sales`)

```
ID  DESCRIPTIONS QTY RATE AMOUNT
--------------------------------
1   APPLE         50  100 1000 
1   APPLE         50  100 1000 
1   APPLE         50  100 1000 
1   APPLE         50  100 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try using a CTE here to arbitrarily delete all but one of the duplicates:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, DESCRIPTIONS, QTY, RATE, AMOUNT
            ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete like following.

```
DELETE A 
FROM   (SELECT Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   partition BY id, descriptions, qty, rate, amount 
                   ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rn 
        FROM   table1) A 
WHERE  a.rn > 1
```

If you want to use `CTE`, you can try like following.

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    partition BY id, descriptions, qty, rate, amount 
                    ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) RN 
         FROM   table1) 
DELETE FROM cte 
WHERE  rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
select distinct * into temp from tableName
delete from tableName
insert into tableName
select * from temp
drop table temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add a column like `rn` and feed it by `row_number() over (Partition by ID,  DESCRIPTIONS ,QTY, RATE, AMOUNT order by Id)`

Now delete the data having `rn` not equal to 1

after completion drop that column... this is a one time solution if it is frequent that add a unique key in your table